# Resolving relative image URL via abs failed

Tags: java, image, url, jsoup, relative-path

I am trying to get images links from a URL.
Some URLs are relative there. So, I am using abs to resolve.
But it unable to resolve, abs unprint the relative URL.

My code without abs:

```
String linktopro = "http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/promises-promises-a-big-obama-health-insurance-promise-that-never-stood-a-chance/2013/10/31/4a465f78-41fd-11e3-b028-de922d7a3f47_story.html";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(linktopro).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").timeout(30000).get();
Elements wp_columns = doc.select("div[class=wp-column ten margin-right main-content]");

for(Element wp_column : wp_columns)
{
    String wp_column_string = wp_column+"";
    Document wp_column_doc = Jsoup.parse(wp_column_string);
    Elements imgs = wp_column_doc.select("img");

    for(Element img : imgs)
    {
        out.println(img.attr("src")+"<br/>");
    }
}
```

Output without abs-

```
/rf/image_606w/2010-2019/Wires/Online/2013-10-31/AP/Images/Obama Health Care.JPEG-09824.jpg
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
```

My code with abs -

```
String linktopro = "http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/promises-promises-a-big-obama-health-insurance-promise-that-never-stood-a-chance/2013/10/31/4a465f78-41fd-11e3-b028-de922d7a3f47_story.html";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(linktopro).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").timeout(30000).get();
Elements wp_columns = doc.select("div[class=wp-column ten margin-right main-content]");

for(Element wp_column : wp_columns)
{
    String wp_column_string = wp_column+"";
    Document wp_column_doc = Jsoup.parse(wp_column_string);
    Elements imgs = wp_column_doc.select("img");
    for(Element img : imgs)
    {
        out.println(img.attr("abs:src")+"<br/>");
    }
}
```

Output with abs -

```
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
http://www.washingtonpost.com/rw/sites/twpweb/img/blogs/spacer.gif
```

As you can see first useful image link disappear.
I do not know why this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
 out.println(img.absUrl("src")+"<br/>");
```